# Navigate back and forth between recently opened files

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

Is there a keyboard shortcut in Sublime to navigate back and forth between recently opened files? Something like Alt+Right and Alt+Left (an example from Eclipse or web browsers). If not, is there a way to create a custom shortcut like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following shortcuts to navigate through different open files:

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>PAGE UP</kbd>   Cycle up through tabs in taborder
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>PAGE DOWN</kbd>   Cycle down through tabs in taborder
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> Next recently used file
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> previous recently used file

More Shortcuts for sublime can be found **[here](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/keyboard_shortcuts_win.html)**.

---

***Custom shortcuts***

Go to `Preferences > Key Bindings-Default` and find the binding that you need and copy the command. The next step is to open `references > Key Bindings-User` where you paste and edit the command.

More concrete info about custom shortcuts can be found **[here](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/customization/key_bindings.html)**.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible if you still have them opened. Other than that

That's <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> / <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>.

Other than that, if you need to have possibility to open recently closed files, you may try doing it with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> (open last closed tab), try [this package](https://github.com/FichteFoll/sublimetext-filehistory) out or even visit [this thread](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=2738) and see if it still works.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a large number of files open, you can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>, and use GoToAnything.

[Unofficial doc information](http://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/file_management/file_management.html)